# Sub queries in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, subquery

I have two mongodb tables named PERSON and DOCUMENTS. I want to get the personName from the PERSON table whose IDs are in the DOCUMENT table. In relational tables query is like this.

```
SELECT personName from PERSON where personID in (SELECT personID from ID)
```

I tried to use aggregate and $lookup functions but it didn't get me the answer I want. The mongo query I used is,

```
db.PERSON.aggregate([

{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "DOCUMENTS",
        "localField": "personID",
        "foreignField": "personID",
        "as": "grp"
    }
}

])
```

This mongo query joins both table and return every fileds. but I want only the personName.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way to do it,

```
db.PERSON.aggregate([

{
"$lookup": {
    "from": "DOCUMENTS",
    "localField": "personID",
    "foreignField": "personID",
    "as": "grp"
}
},
{"$unwind" : "$grp"},
{"$project" : {
    "personName" : 1
}

])
```